# Association Injection or Dependency Injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, associations, uml

I'm studying the dependency injection pattern. I have read many examples, among which one typical example is to use XxxService/XxxRepository as example. But from my opinion, according to the UML concept, class XxxRepository should be an association of class XxxService. Why not call this situation **Association Injection**, but still Dependency Injection?:)

Thanks!

**UPDATE ON 1/26/2018**

I currently think the concept of `dependency injection` is suitable for the situation described in this question. Because **Association** is just a special **Dependency** in UML.

[Please refer to this article](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DependencyAndAssociation.html), Martin Fowler said:

> "a dependency exists between two elements if changes to the definition of one element (the supplier) may cause changes to the other (the client)". 
>   This is a very vague and general relationship, which is why the UML
>   has a host of stereotypes for different forms of dependency.

and

> Associations also imply dependency, if there is an association between two classes, there is also a dependency.

So I cannot accept any answers right now. Or maybe this question is not a good question because every developer has his owned viewpoint. I'm seriously considering to close this question.

Comment: Why people have called something they did can only be speculated (so opinion based and off-topic here). Please remove that part of your question.

Comment: @ThomasKilian true in some case.  However, there is sometimes an historical background or a known and documented reason which sets some of these naming questions perfectly well in scope.

Comment: @Christophe Sometimes. Here they are like chimp and gorilla both descending from a common predecessor: "dependency" in the word's basic sense. Else they are not related. So if the chimp developed further to bonobo or UML-dependency to UML-association does not matter for the gorilla.

Answer (score 1):

Because dependency injection is defined for coding not for design.

You can code an association with or without injection, but it is an association.

For example, in Java, the following codes show an association between a classe A and a class B implementing interface IB.

`class A{
    @Inject
    private IB b;
    ...
    }`

or

`Class A{
    private IB b = new B();
    ...
   }`

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**: I want to clarify some hints about **Dependency Injection**.

In Dependency Injection (see [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#cite_note-HollywoodPrinciple.c2-2) (4th paragraph)):

> - The client does not need to know how to construct the services.
> - The client does not need to know **which actual services** it is using.
> - The client only needs to know about the **intrinsic interfaces** of the services because these define how the client may use the services.

When we are using the dependency injection like below code:

```
class A {
    @Inject
    private IB b;

    //...
}
```

We do not actually know, which object of which class (that implements `IB`) was injected to `b`.

Maybe the injected class changes at runtime, maybe it changes because of some configurations that handled manually or automatically. Maybe it changes dynamically as period of time and etc.

So, we can not use an association between class `A` and other class (which class? or which object?)

**Therefore**, there is only dependency between class `A` and interface `IB`.

In small projects, maybe we have only one implementation of `IB` in our project. Or we do not have any mechanism to have dynamic injections. In this case, association may be used. However, in this case, there is no need to Dependency Injection.

To find good explanation from Martin Fowler and good example, see [reference 2](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).